# C++ For Loop inside a While loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to write a program which takes measurements from a user and inputs them into a vector. The while loop continues until the user inputs '|' at which point it breaks out of the loops and prints the measurements. The problem I am having however is that when trying to add the measurements to the vector. I have used the debugger and found that the loops never actually enters the for loop, thus not being able to reach the "push_back statement".

This program is part of the drills in the Bjarne Stroustup PPP c++ book.

```
 #include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

double metreConvert (double userInput , String unit) {

if (unit == "cm")
userInput = userInput / 100;
else if (unit == "in")
userInput = (userInput * 2.54) / 100;
else if (unit == "ft")
userInput = ((userInput * 12) * 2.54) / 100;
else if (unit == "m")
userInput;

return userInput;
}

void numbers() {
double input; 
String unit;
vector <double> measurements;

    while (cin >> input >> unit && input != '|'){
    if (unit == "cm")
    input = input / 100;
    else if (unit == "in")
    input = (input * 2.54) / 100;
    else if (unit == "ft")
    input = ((input * 12) * 2.54) / 100;
    else if (unit == "m")
    input;
        for (int i=0; measurements.size(); i++){
            if (i == 0 || input != measurements[i]){
            cout << "\nPopping onto vector";
            measurements.push_back(input);
            }
            else {
            cout << "\nMeasurment cannot be placed on vector";

        }
        }
    }
    cout << "input ended";
    }

void main() {
cout << "Please enter a number followed by a unit(metres,cm,inches,ft), type '|' when finished inputing:";
numbers();
 }
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly. Also, what does `input;` just before the `for` loop do?

Comment: measurements.size() -- maybe check if that not 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Remy said, plus:

The second part of a for loop declaration is a condition, which should evaluate to either true or false. In your case, your condition is `measurements.size()`

Problem is that you don't have anything in your measurements vector, so measurements.size() will return 0. Which is equivalent to false. I suspect this is not really what you wanted to do, you probably meant something like:

```
for (int i=0; i < measurements.size(); i++){
```

Even with that, your logic is wrong. Assuming you're just trying to add each entered value into the measurements vector (if it is not equal to the previous measurement), I don't see why you need a for loop here at all. This will do what you want:

```
while (cin >> input >> unit && input != '|')
{
    if (unit == "cm")
        input = input / 100;
    else if (unit == "in")
        input = (input * 2.54) / 100;
    else if (unit == "ft")
        input = ((input * 12) * 2.54) / 100;
    else if (unit == "m")
        input;    //No idea what this is supposed to be - more missing code?

    if (!measurements.size() || input != measurements[measurements.size()-1])
    {
        cout << "\nPopping onto vector";
        measurements.push_back(input);
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "\nMeasurment cannot be placed on vector";
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers mate, this was a great help

Answer (score 3):

`input` is a `double`.  `|` is a `char`.  They are not the same thing.  So `cin` fails and your `while` loop is not entered.  To do what you are attempting, you need to input the data as a `string` first, check its value for `|`, and if not a match then convert it to a `double` for further processing.

Comment: I know that | is a character and I'm inputting into a double, but I have gotten the code to work without the for loop, I'm adding that in so users cannot add in the same thing twice.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
for (int i=0; measurements.size(); i++){
```

causes the loop to run forever if the `measurements` vector is not empty (and not at all if the vector is empty).  Perhaps you meant

```
i < measurements.size()
```